# Bigquery - How to in crease the expiration time of tables in free sandbox?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using the free bigquery sandbox to generate some custom metrics based on my analytics data. I have read in the documentation that the expiration time of table in free account is 60 days. What does this expiration time means ? What will exactly happen after 60 days. All my datas will be lost ? How can i increase the expiration time in this case ? Should i need to pay for it ? If yes, what will be the cost ?

Comment: The tables/data is deleted. If you want to keep anything past 60 days, you'll need to upgrade. It's all in the docs. _"To overcome the sandbox limits, you can upgrade your project and remove or update the expiration time for your resources. After upgrading from the sandbox, BigQuery Quotas and limits still apply."_ https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/sandbox#limits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/sandbox#limits):

> The BigQuery sandbox gives you free access to the power of BigQuery
>   subject to the sandbox's limits. The sandbox allows you to use the web
>   UI in the Cloud Console without providing a credit card. You can use
>   the sandbox without creating a billing account or enabling billing for
>   your project.

In addition, according to the [limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/sandbox#limits) :

> All datasets have the default table expiration time and the default
>   partition expiration set to 60 days. Any tables, views, or partitions
>   in partitioned tables automatically expire after 60 days.

You can edit this expiration date if your data is exported to BigQuery but, in order to do that, you have to upgrade the project's plan to use it (if needed). Then you would be billed by the amount of bytes processed, you can check the billing options [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing).

Thus, within BigQuery you can edit the expiration date. In BigQuery, you go to ***Project > Dataset > Table > Details > click in the pencil next to the table's name and  set expiration date to never or select a date***. As follows:

[image]